# Question on inputs of PRFs and HKDF KDF

Tags: random-number-generator, key-derivation, pseudo-random-function, hkdf

I've read a lot of information about PRNGs, PRFs and KDFs. As far as I know:

PRNG: The seed for the PRNG must be a uniform string. It transforms a short real uniform string into some bits of pseudo-randomness.

PRF: The PRF gets a uniform key and some additional input and transforms it  into a string of pseudo-randomness.

KDF: For example the HKDF scheme uses the hmac as PRF and does not need any uniform input string. It generates some pseudo-randomness.

So far, is that right? I would like to get some additional information about literature on that topcs, in particular further on the inputs of PRF and KDF.

Comment: _The_ reference on KDFs and their security models and guarantees is probably t[he introductionary paper for HKDF](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/264).

Comment: Hi, yes I already know hat paper. May be I did not understand the fully impact and consequences of that paper. But the most important question to me is: Is it right, that the KDF (f.e. the HKDF-Scheme) does not need any uniform input string? although it would be better, as far as I understood it, if it were?